# Deploy Database Project with MSBuild with CommandLine Parameters fails

Tags: deployment, msbuild, publish, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I am failing to deploy Database project using command line parameters with msbuild. I would like to:

- use publish xml profile
- define connection string as command line parameter

but this seems to be impossible for no reason. There is for sure some simple catch I am missing. I tried following variants:

`msbuild /t:SqlDeploy /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="test.publish.xml" /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=..." Database.sqlproj`

- deploys database
- values in test.pubhlish.xml are **ignored**

`msbuild /t:Build /t:Deploy /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="test.publish.xml" /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=..." Database.sqlproj`

- deploys database
- values in test.pubhlish.xml are **ignored**

`msbuild /t:Build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="test.publish.xml" /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=..." Database.sqlproj`

- **fails** with error: `Deploy Error : The connection string is not valid`
- values in test.publish.xml file are used (when test.publish.xml contains TargetConnectionString, database is deployed correctly)

In all 3 cases I am using exactly the same ConnectionString, so it is not a typo or error in the connection string. I need to use the 3rd variant, but this just fails.. What am I missing?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It seems impossible to oversteeer the connection string from the publish profile. MSDeploy understands that though...

Comment: @Lukas K did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same challenge.

Comment: kind of.. Have a look on [SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-2017) tool. It can publish DACPAC project with the option to pass connection string as parameter. You create DACPAC with msbuild and deploy it with SqlPackage. Hope this helps.